# Angular 8: Is it possible to create only one instance of services inside shared module

Tags: angular, typescript, singleton

I have a `shared.module` which has several services and pipes. I want to have only one instances of those services globally. If I import `shared.module` inside other modules, more than one instance were created. I also tried importing `shared.module` inside `aap.module` but it didn't work.

Comment: What I can suggest is to set service per module, if It will be used as a shared service across all the applications it should be injected in the root module, otherwise you can provide service per module, for example UserService imported in UserModule and not SharedModule

Answer (score 5):

It could be archived by providing service in the root without importing it into any module.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserService {
}
```

[Angular documentation has more details about providing scope.](https://angular.io/guide/providers#provider-scope)

Comment: Are there any other ways of doing it?

Comment: Providing in `AppModule` should give the same result. Some tricks with provider factory and global object (eg `window`) might work as well.

Comment: @NamanJain did u got anything I am on the same page now. Need single instance of the service and shared module is imported in multiple modules.

Comment: `export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<SharedModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [DummyService, StorageService, RequestService, RouterGuard, HttpService],
    };
  }
}` something like this. And remove any of these services in any other providers.